# Unable to create a Docker secret from STDIN

Tags: docker, conemu, docker-secrets

I'm trying to create a Docker secret as per Docker docs:

> $ echo  | docker secret create my_secret -

and getting the following:

```
$ echo 'this is my secret' | docker secret create my-secret -
Error reading content from "-": Incorrect function.
```

This is running under Docker Toolbox in ConEmu:

```
$ docker version                                         
Client:                                                  
 Version:      17.07.0-ce                                
 API version:  1.31                                      
 Go version:   go1.8.3                                   
 Git commit:   8784753                                   
 Built:        Tue Aug 29 17:41:05 2017                  
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64                             

Server:                                                  
 Version:      17.09.0-ce                                
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)               
 Go version:   go1.8.3                                   
 Git commit:   afdb6d4                                   
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:45:38 2017                  
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64                               
 Experimental: false
```

The behavior manifests itself only for the STDIN option, the command works fine for a file:

```
$ docker secret create my_secret ./secret.txt
ulec3yck5jpwywg6o7ptxnun7  

$ openssl rand -base64 32 | docker secret create secure-secret -
Error reading content from "-": Incorrect function.  

$ echo "mydatabasepassword" | docker secret create db_pass -
Error reading content from "-": Incorrect function.
```

Comment: Run the command in a bash shell.

Comment: Or you can also try an see if ConEmu supports this `echo 'this is my secret' | docker secret create my-secret /dev/stdin`

Comment: @BMitch: It is docker bash shell.  @Tarun Lalwani: `$ echo 'this is my secret' | docker secret create my-secret /dev/stdin
open /dev/stdin: The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: ConEmu is a terminal. What shell do you use to run your "docker" command?

Comment: @Maximus: As I understand, ConEmu automatically configures itself under Tools::Docker when Docker Toolbox is installed.  Here's what I see in its Task configuration box: `"%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\..\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe"-l -i "%DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH%\start.sh" -new_console:t:"Docker"`.  Would it be fair to assume that bash is used here?

Comment: Sure. So, run this command outside of ConEmu (without -new_console of course) and check your issue.

Comment: @Maximus: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I was facing the same issue on Docker for Windows, using Cmder (which I believe also uses/is conemu, I'm unsure) but was getting the same error, I tried a standard Windows command prompt and it worked fine, however even running Windows Powershell in Cmder wouldn't work, but running the native Windows Powershell command it worked fine